# QBO data object for TrialBalance

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

It look like the SDK for VS C# doesn't have the Trial Balance report object included. Is this correct, and if so, when is the update for this planned, and are there any code examples of how to 'Roll Your Own'.

Thanks

Comment: Support for QBO reports in the SKD would available by 4th April as per the communication we have.

Comment: Any update on the availability of the update?

Answer (score 0):

It is released recently in production. Updated devkit will also be published soon.

Please have a look at the following links

- https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/03/25/the-quickbooks-online-reports-api-has-arrived
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/reports
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/reports/trialbalance

Thanks